# Zoom H6 - Record electric guitar with pedals

Tags: electric-guitar, recording, microphones

I was wondering how the [Zoom H6](https://www.zoom-na.com/products/field-video-recording/field-recording/h6-handy-recorder/features) recorder performed when recording "heavy" electric guitar. I would like to plug my electric guitar plus some pedals (Whammy, Delay, Reverb & Big Muff) and mix it on my computer.

It seems possible to [plug](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-6q6X8G3Y8Tr/learn/zoom-h6-handheld-6-track-digital-recorder-review.html) the guitar directly into the Zoom.
Do you have any experience using the Zoom as a Audio Interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The H6 offers Mic and Line inputs.  If your effects chain ends up at Line level you can connect it directly.  If it ends up at "guitar" level, you'll need to run it through something that makes it look like a Line or Mic source first.

"All four main H6 inputs (inputs 1-4) are combo connectors that can accept either XLR or ¼” balanced or unbalanced phone cables. They can handle both mic- and line-level signals, which means that you can connect either external microphones or line-level devices like mixers, portable music players, electronic keyboards, or electric guitars or basses with active electronics (passive electric guitars or basses can also be connected with the use of a mixer or effects device)."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean exactly by guitar level ? Do you have any idea how good the sound is ? thanks

Comment: Voltages  can vary considerably.  100mv is often quoted, but some guitars can produce as much as 1v.  It needs to be treated as a voltage source into a high-impedence input.  If this is all jargon to you, don't worry.  The main point is that a guitar pickup won't sound good into a socket labelled "mic" or "Line In", even if the plug DOES fit.

Comment: Ok thank you. So in conclusion I should not use the Zoom H6 as Audio interface for my electric guitar ? Thanks.

Comment: The interface is not optimum.   But sound will get through, and electric guitar is all about manipulation and effects, not about pure amplification.  If it's all you've got try.  If you like the sound you get, then it's good.

Answer (score 1):

I've been exploring this option as well and the easy solution is buying an active DI Box. Try to find one with a 1 Megaohm Input.